# ClearCase can I use clearexport_ccase/clearimport to copy VOB data to a VOB on a different machine

Tags: clearcase

ClearCase can I use clearexport_ccase/clearimport to copy VOB data to a VOB on a different machine at a different location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> copy VOB data to a VOB on a different machine at a different location?

That kind of process means a `reformatvob -dump` / `reformatvob -load`:

```
cleartool reformatvob -dump /vobstore/avob.vbs
```

The process is described in "[Moving VOBs and relocating VOB data](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/vob-relo-mv.htm)".
It uses the command [`refomatvob`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_reformatvob.htm).

`clearfsimport` wouldn't import all the metadata (stream, labels, projects, ...): only files and directories.