# upgrading clearcase from 7.1.2.5 to 8.X

Tags: installation, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We got Clearcase multisite environment which includes four sites...

```
•   Main site hosted on RHEL 5.3 (Tikanga) with CC version 7.1.2.5  
•   Two more sites hosted on Solaris 10 with CC version 7.0.1.8.   
•   Last site on Windows server 2003 SP2 with CC version 7.0.1.8
```

> database schema version: 54
>   VOB family feature level: 5
>   License is Atria.

we are looking forward to upgrade to clearcase version 8.x due to end of support of 7.1.2 version.

Believe lots of folks could have done this, Appreciate if you could share your experience and upgrade guide for us.

Waiting for your valuable updates.

*Have started my planning, will update this thread with my question and my finding too.*

1. Mostly windows client with version 7.0.1.8, Can this same version talk to CC server with 8.X ?

BRs
Mani.

Comment: link to licensing --> http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rational/v0r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.license.doc/topics/c_node_upgrading.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mostly windows client with version 7.0.1.8, Can this same version talk to CC server with 8.X ?

That would be addressed by the "[Compatibility across releases for ClearCase clients and servers](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21597061)"

That shows CC clients and view servers, even in 7.0.x, are mostly compatible with a Vob Server in 8.x.

Having done many migrations of that type, you want to:

- test that compatibility of those old clients with a test vob server
- Make sure new CC clients are available for users to migrate when they are ready
- Check that uninstalling their old client / installing the new ClearTeam 7.x client is documented (because they might have to re-create their views, since ClearTeam supports now dynamic view and special snapshot "web" views)

Comment: Started planning migration activity for new site. This got around 120 vobs, Server is windows 2003. Plan is we are getting new server with 2008 and wanted to move setup. Vob and View Server are in windows. CC version is 7.1

Comment: Any idea how much time does it takes for the entire activity? Here view server is also getting changed.

Comment: Will unregister, untag , move the vob content in new server with 8.X tag and register will work ?

Comment: It depends on the number of vobs/view. Moving is pl if the architecture is the same, but I prefer dumping / reloding (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18878850/6309). Make sure to test first. A typical migration can take a full day (again, depending on the volume of data to move) in order to dump/reload and check that everything work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for input, May I know why you prefer dumping please.

Comment: @maestromani less file to transfer (one big dump and few others), in a format that easily reloaded on any other server. Less file to copy means less corruption risk during the transfer.